# ! character to invoke the search in zsh

Tags: zsh

There is a very nice feature that I love in ZSH. When you type the ! character followed by a word + TAB key, it makes the shell to pull up the last command beginning with the word followed by the ! and expand it; e.g.:

```
% !ssh
```

Then, the expected behavior is that you can use the up and down arrow keys to cycle through the history with the scope limited to those commands that start with **ssh**. Now, I get this working in Mac OS X, but for some reason I don't get it on my linux box. My bindkeys looks like this in my linux installation:

```
 user@host ⮀ ~ ⮀ bindkey | fgrep history
"^N" down-line-or-history
"^O" accept-line-and-down-history
"^P" up-line-or-history
"^R" history-incremental-search-backward
"^S" history-incremental-search-forward
"^X^N" infer-next-history
"^Xr" history-incremental-search-backward
"^Xs" history-incremental-search-forward
"^[ " expand-history
"^[!" expand-history
"^[," _history-complete-newer
"^[/" _history-complete-older
"^[<" beginning-of-buffer-or-history
"^[>" end-of-buffer-or-history
"^[N" history-search-forward
"^[OA" up-line-or-history
"^[OB" down-line-or-history
"^[P" history-search-backward
"^[[5~" up-line-or-history
"^[[6~" down-line-or-history
"^[n" history-search-forward
"^[p" history-search-backward
```

What's the bindkey I'd have to change in order of getting the behavior expected? I have already changed some of them, but the result is not the desired. I'd be glad if somebody could help me. The version of zsh I have installed is 5.0.2.

**Edited on Thu May 30 10:27:49 CEST 2013:**

@Francisco it worked. I didn't know that the needed option was up-line-or-search and down-line-or-search. So I did as follows:

1) I checked which keys were assigned:

```
⮀ ~/.dotfiles ⮀ ⭠ ihacku ⮀ bindkey | fgrep search 
"^R" history-incremental-search-backward
"^S" history-incremental-search-forward
"^Xr" history-incremental-search-backward
"^Xs" history-incremental-search-forward
"^[N" history-search-forward
"^[OA" up-line-or-search
"^[OB" down-line-or-search
"^[P" history-search-backward
"^[[A" up-line-or-search
"^[[B" down-line-or-search
"^[n" history-search-forward
"^[p" history-search-backward
```

2) Then, I typed `Ctrl + v` followed by up arrow, and then down arrow and I got:

```
⮀ ~/.dotfiles ⮀ ⭠ ihacku ⮀ ^[OA
⮀ ~/.dotfiles ⮀ ⭠ ihacku ⮀ ^[OB
```

3) I added your code to my .zshrc:

```
bindkey '^[OA' up-line-or-search                                                
bindkey '^[OB' down-line-or-search
```

**Note:** I added these lines after `oh-my-zsh.sh` is loaded.

5) I sourced my .zsh:

```
. ~/.zshrc
```

And finally I get the expected result. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to make sure that `up-line-or-search` is bounded to the `"up-arrow"` key (whichever its character code). At my own `.zshrc` (running on top of Linux), I get this done with

```
bindkey '^[[A' up-line-or-search
bindkey '^[[B' down-line-or-search
```

Note that these functions are assigned but to `"^[[5~"`...